# How to add an ARRAY to an associative array as key value pair

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-push

This is my associative array.

```
 $family = array("Mike"=>array("Ben","klatty","Paul"),"Johnson"=>array("Shena", "Glenn"));

 $family['shrinidhi']=array("akshata","pandu");
```

this works fine.

I would like to push an array into $family dynamically.
i.e

```
$family['$contact["values"][$i]["contact_id"]']= array($phone_nums[$i]['values'][$j]['phone'],$phone_nums[$i]['values'][$j]['phone_type_id']));
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need `(')` quote when you are using variable value in index

change

```
$family['$contact["values"][$i]["contact_id"]']
```

to

```
$family[$contact["values"][$i]["contact_id"]]
```